# What's the relation between two symmetry groups, if one has all the symmetry of the other and some more?

Tags: terminology, symmetry

##### Question:

Consider two [molecular symmetry groups](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Molecular_symmetry#Symmetry_groups), for example $C_s$ and $C_{2v}$.

- $C_s$ has one inversion plane, and two irreductible representations: the symmetric $A'$, and the antisymmetric $A''$.
- $C_{2v}$ has one inversion plane and one 2-fold axis; and four irreductible representations: $A_1$, $B_1$, $A_2$, $B_2$.

It is clear that if a molecule has a $C_{2v}$ symmetry, it also has a $C_s$ symmetry. It also stands (in a selected coordinate system), that an orbital of a molecule with $C_{2v}$ symmetry that belong to $A_1$ or $B_1$ also belong to $A'$, and similarly, orbitals belonging to $A_2$ and $B_2$ also belong to $A''$.

1. What mathematical term describes the relationship between $C_s$ and $C_{2v}$? Is $C_{2v}$ a *subgroup* of $C_s$? Is it rather a *subset* of it? Should we rather say that $C_{2v}$ *implies* $C_s$?
2. What's the correct term for the relationship between $A_1$/$B_1$ and $A'$, and between $A_2$/$B_2$ and $A''$? Are they *subspecies*? Does $A_1$ *imply* $A'$?

##### Background:

I'm comparing some orbitals of two similar molecules. One is a root with $C_{2v}$ symmetry, and the other is an alkylated version of it with $C_s$ symmetry. For certain reasons, symmetry classifications of the molecules play an important part of the writeup.  I want to explicitly point out that the symmetry and the irreductable representations of the root correspond to the ones of the alkylated molecule, even though they're labeled differently.

While this sounds like a basic question, I found it surprisingly hard to find an answer. I've been struggling for almost a week at this point. All textbooks and online resources talk about how you can obtain $C_{2v}$ from $C_s$ with certain symmetry operations, and about what properties they have individually, but never mention the terms I'm looking for.

I don't really have a strong background in group theory, so if I used any other terms incorrectly, I'm glad to be corrected.

Comment: With groups, **subgroup** is indeed the correct word. Smaller group is a subgroup of the bigger one.

Comment: I think you mean "irreducible". I'm not aware of "irreductible" being used, but I could be unaware of its use. "orbitals belonging to A2 and B2 also belong to A′′"
My understanding is that elements of A2, B2, and A'' represent symmetries of the molecules. Aren't the symmetries of the molecules different from orbitals? "One is a root with C_{2v} symmetry, and the other is an alkylated version of it with C_s symmetry." Alkylating makes molecules more symmetric?

Comment: @Acccumulation 1) $C_{2v}$ is *more* symmetric than $C_s$ as it also has a 2-fold axis in addition to the inversion plane. 2) Irreps are not the same as symmetries. Vaguely (in this case) they classify whether the orbitals are symmetric or antisymmetric WRT to the specific symmetry operations of the group, but u/orthocresol is much more equipped to comment on this. 3) re spelling, I'll check, it may be a typo that sticks around in my team.

Comment: If the user who downvoted the question could gently provide an explanation, I'd be more than glad to attempt to improve it. Right now I'm unsure what's the issue.

Comment: @Neinstein I wouldn't worry about it too much; in my experience there's a slightly higher (but still low) level of spurious background downvotes without comments here than in some other STEM sites.

Comment: "It is clear that if a molecule has a $C_{2v}$
 symmetry, it also has a $C_s$
 symmetry." Doesn't that mean that $C_{2v}$ has fewer symmetries?

Comment: @Acccumulation If a molecule has a symmetry plane and a 2-fold axis, ergo has a $C_{2v}$ symmetry, then it has a symmetry plane ergo $C_v$ symmetry. I'm not sure why this would mean that $C_{2v}$ has *less* symmetries.

Comment: If I say "Everyone who has a TV also has a phone", does it not follow that there are more phones than TV? "If something has an X then it has a Y" implies that there are more Y than X. The disagreement may stem from the question of whether "symmetry" refers to an automorphism that preserves some quality, or a group of such automorphisms. You seem to be using in the latter sense (and if so, it might be better to say "$C_s$ symmetry" rather than "a $C_s$ symmetry".

Comment: If "a symmetry" refer to an automorphism rather the group of such, then the statement "If G has a symmetry, then H has that symmetry" means that H is more symmetric than G, because every automorphism in G is also in H. There's the further confusion engendered by you asking "Is $C_{2v}$ a subgroup of $C_s$?" If G is a subgroup of H, then H is more symmetric than  G.

Comment: @Acccumulation I'm not sure I'm following. Your example with the TVS and mobiles would translate to "there are more molecules with Cs symmetry than with C2v", which certainly stands.

Comment: @Acccumulation I also don't really follow the second point with G and H. C2v has all the symmetry elements of Cs and one more, therefore C2v is more symmetric (I.e. describes a higher degree of symmetry). You seem to state the opposite which feels disingenuous to me. The groups don't have the symmetries themselves (what would that even mean), they are groups consisting of symmetry operations. A molecule is then said to have e.g. Cs symmetry if it's invariant to all symmetry operations in Cs.

Comment: My example with TVs translates to your statement meaning that there are more $C_s$ symmetries, not more molecules with $C_s$ symmetry. Also, $C_{2v}$ has more than just one more symmetry than $C_s$. I am not saying that $C_s$ has more elements, I'm saying that *your wording* implies this. And calling me "disingenuous" is a rather uncivil accusation.

Comment: @Accumulation I didn't call you disingenuous, I called my interpretation of your comment seemingly disingenuous. I didn't mean to offend you.

Comment: @Neinstein "[You seem to state the opposite which feels disingenuous to me](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/172336/whats-the-relation-between-two-symmetry-groups-if-one-has-all-the-symmetry-of?noredirect=1#comment363047_172336)" does mean that if Accumulation stated what you feel they "seem to state", then they were being "not candid or sincere, typically by pretending that one knows less about something than one really does." (from google). Perhaps it's not the word you were looking for? Or perhaps you meant to say "...feels disingenuous **of** me" instead of "to me"?

Comment: @uhoh Probably I used the word wrongly. English is not my native, and until now I believed "disingenious" is pretty much a slightly stronger but still formal and uncharged synonym of "unintuitive". I've seen it a couple times on SE in contexts which led me to this interpretation. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1. What mathematical term describes the relationship between $C_s$ and $C_{2v}$? Is $C_{2v}$ a *subgroup* of $C_s$? Is it rather a *subset* of it? Should we rather say that $C_{2v}$ *implies* $C_s$?

$C_\mathrm{s}$ is a subgroup of $C_\mathrm{2v}$, yes.

I'm speaking *very* informally here, but a group is a set of elements, together with a binary operator $*$ that 'combines' the elements to form other elements. In the case of symmetry groups, these elements are symmetry operations. The binary operator is composition, i.e. $B * A$ means do symmetry operation $A$ first and then $B$ (or the other way round, it's just a matter of definition); and it turns out that $B * A$ is always also a symmetry element. So, a group has more structure than just a set. A set is just a collection of elements, it doesn't have to have a way to combine them.

It's true that the *elements* of $C_\mathrm{s}$ are a subset of the *elements* of $C_\mathrm{2v}$. However, when referring to the groups themselves, subgroup is the correct term.

I don't think 'implies' is appropriate here, that's typically used in a context like propositional logic.

> 2. What's the correct term for the relationship between $A_1$/$B_1$ and $A'$, and between $A_2$/$B_2$ and $A''$? Are they *subspecies*? Does $A_1$ *imply* $A'$?

$A$, $B$, etc. are representations of a group. Defining the word 'representation' is actually quite involved! I've written a bit about it [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/157642/16683) before, but it's a whirlwind tour, and I don't necessarily think it makes for good reading.

If you're just looking for the correct term, though, then my understanding is that $A'$ is the *restriction* of the representation $A_1$ to the subgroup $C_\mathrm{s}$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_representation

Writing this in a chemistry paper/report will probably throw most readers off. (I reckon most chemists probably don't understand the formal meaning of a subgroup, but would have an intuitive understanding of it. I don't think a restricted representation means anything to the typical chemist, though, except for the very mathematically inclined.) So if I were in your position, I'd probably write that there is a 'correspondence' or a 'correlation' between the two irreps. That's not super-precise language, in that it doesn't describe the nature of the 'correspondence', but it'll get the message across. (Of course, you could define it properly once at the beginning, and then stick to vague language afterwards.)

For a different perspective, these kinds of relationships between representations are tabulated in so-called *descent in symmetry tables*, which you can find online. I also spent some time typing them up on [Chemistry Meta](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3435/16683), and in the original source from Atkins et al., similarly vague language is used:

> The following tables show the correlation between the irreducible representations of a group and those of some of its subgroups. In a number of cases more than one correlation exists between groups.

Comment: "I also spent some time..." seems like a bit of an understatement :-)

Answer (score 3):

As the discussion of these issues in the comments has gotten rather extensive, I think that I should move it to an answer.

In math, it's common to use the word "symmetry" to refer to an automorphism that leaves an object essentially the same. For example, see [this page](http://www.markronan.com/mathematics/symmetry-corner/the-rotations-of-a-cube) that says that a cube has 48 symmetries. Thus, what you refer to as a "symmetry operation" would in math often be referred to as simply a "symmetry".

As another example, a benzene molecule, if we ignore the single/double bond issue, has 12 symmetries, six rotations and six reflections. This is known as the [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) (note the statement "A regular polygon with n sides has 2n different symmetries", again using the word "symmetry" to refer to an automorphism) $D_6$. There are 12 symmetries in $D_6$. $D_6$ is a group of symmetries.

If we alkylate one of the carbon atoms (don't worry if this doesn't make sense chemically, I'm just dealing with the math), then the molecule has only one non-trivial symmetry (a reflection about the alkylated carbon). This is the binary or $Z_2$ group. If we alkylate two carbon atoms at opposite side of the molecule, then there are four symmetries, all of which are members of $D_6$. Since all symmetries of alkylated molecules are members of $D_6$, it would be correct to say "If the alkylated molecule has a symmetry, then the root has that symmetry".

Note that there is only one way to have a non-alkylated benzene molecule, but many different ways to have an alkylated benzene molecule. So:

- The root has more symmetries than the alkylated molecule.
- For each symmetry, if the alkylated molecule has that symmetry, then the root does as well. For instance, if a molecule has a $Z_2$ symmetry, then it has a $D_6$ symmetry.
- The root is more symmetric than the alkylated molecule.
- There are more alkylated molecules than root molecules [at least, in terms of possible configurations, not necessarily instances].
- The symmetry group of the alkylated molecule is a subgroup of the root's.

Note that there is an opposite relationship between the first and fourth of these points. If the symmetry group of things of type X is a subgroup of the symmetry group of things of type Y, then the set of things of type Y is a subset of the set of things of type X.

For your question "Is $C_{2v}$ a subgroup of $C_s$?" the answer is a definite "no"; $C_s$ is a subgroup of $C_{2v}$. Your statement "It is clear that if a molecule has a $C_{2v}$ symmetry, it also has a $C_s$ symmetry." is misleading at best. It would be more clear as "It is clear that if a molecule has is invariant under $C_{2v}$, then it is invariant under $C_s$."

Comment: I've been following the discussion and while I'm not a chemist I struggle with symmetries of unit cells in crystals (cf. [Is the completeness of the 230 known space groups in three dimensions proven?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3797248/284619)) and wonder if a question something like "How closely related are molecular symmetry groups to space groups used in crystallography? Are there also 230 of them?" could might be askable here, in [Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) or in Math SE?

Comment: Also, any thoughts on [Straightforward formalism to get sets of lattice vectors of fcc (111), (110) and (100) facet surfaces that I can also cite?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6364/201) A comment there suggests "don’t you just have one set of unique lattice vectors and the rest could be computed by symmetry operations?" but no further insight on symmetry operations were forthcoming. My theory is that matter modelers just let their big commercial programs handle all things symmetry-relate and don't really want to wade into it explicitly :-)